# Is it possible to reuse the code to update/insert record in multple tables from multiple WinFoms

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-tables

I have this code to insert record into Table Products.

```
int insertRecordIntoProduct()
{
   try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
       string insQuery = "insert into product_details (prod_name,prod_desc,prod_status,start_date,end_date,ref_num,ror) "+  
                         "values(@p_name,@p_desc,@status,@sdate,@edate,@filenum,@ror)";

    SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insQuery, con);

    insertCmd.Parameters.Clear();
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_name", txtProdName.Text);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_desc", txtProdDesc.Text);

    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", (StartDatePicker.Value.Date)); 
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edate", (EndDatePicker.Value.Date)); 
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filenum", txtBoxFileNum.Text);

   int r= insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    return r;
   }
}
```

This code is working fine. My Problem is that I have 10-12 wiforms and each form need to insert/update record in different Tables into same database. Now I want to know that can I use the above code in any way to insert/update record from various forms that have different no. of TextBoxes (for ex. - my CustomerDetail form have 15 TextBoxes, Brokerage form have 8 TexBoxes etc.) or I have to do to the same for each form(whichh take a lot time).
Also tell me if there is any other alternative to do this in best manner.

Comment: do all have same parameters to insert?

Comment: @EhsanUllah - OP indicated in his question that the forms have different numbers of text boxes (which appear to be used as parameters), so I would suspect that the answer to your question is no.

Comment: yea right Tim.. all have different parameters....

Comment: You should only learn the `ADO.NET` at basic level because we now have `LINQ to SQL` and `Entity Framework`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a class that is used by all the forms, and in that class have one method that you can use for updates/inserts, and perhaps another for selects (since you'll be returning data).

For example:

```
public static class SqlHelper
{

    public static int InsertUpdate(string connectionString, string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {

        int rows = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            sqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, parameters[key]);
            }

            rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return rows;
    }
}
```

What this code does is takes a string value for the connection string, a string value for the SQL command, and a Dictionary that has the parameter name(s) as a key and the corresponding value.

It then creates a SqlConnection, creates the command, and iterates through the parameters dictionary and adds a new parameter to the command for each parameter in the dictionary.

Finally, it executes the query and returns the rows affected.

You could then call this method as follows (based on your example code):

```
int rowsAffected = 0;

try
{
    Dictionary<string, object>() params = new Dictionary(string, object>();
    params.Add("@p_name", txtProdName.Text);
    params.Add("@p_desc", txtProdDesc.Text);
    params.Add("@sdate", StartDatePicker.Value.Date);
    params.Add("@edate", EndDatePicker.Value.Date);
    params.Add("@filenum", txtBoxFileNum.Text);

    string sql = "insert into product_details" +      
                 "(prod_name,prod_desc,prod_status,"+
                 "start_date,end_date,ref_num,ror) "+
                 "values(@p_name,@p_desc,@status,@sdate,@edate,@filenum,@ror)";

   rowsAffected = SqlHelper.InsertUpdate(connectionString, sql, params);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Do something with the error;
}
```

I wrapped the call in a try catch block so you have a way of handling any errors in the underlying method call.  The dictionary is built, the sql string is built, and then rowsAffected is assigned the value returned by the static helper method (`SqlHelper.InsertUpdate`).

If an error is encountered, it is caught and you can do something with it (log it, message box, etc)

This example expects the `connectionString` string to already be filled (most likely at the class level).

Since a Dictionary is used to pass in the parameters, you simply need to create a new dictionary for each call, with the proper number of parameters in it to match the SQL command (note that in your posted code example you don't have anything for `@ror`, so I didn't include it).

You could also add a second static method to the `SqlHelper` class for selecting data - in this case you could return a `DataTable`, `DataSet` or `SqlDataReader`, depending on what you preferred to use - or even have one method for each.

Comment: thank @Tim. this is what i want .
one more think can we use generic List<T> in place of Dictionary..?

Comment: @Vimdav - you could use a `List<T>`, but you would lose flexibility - you'd either have to have two `List<T>` (one for the parameter name, one for the parameter value), or you'd have to explicitly use either the parameter name or parameter value, and then you would lose the ability to add a varying number of parameters (with their values) with a simple foreach loop.  A dictionary is a much better fit for your needs.

Comment: @Vimdav - good choice.  Note that if you're only passing in `TextBox`s (i.e., string values) and you won't ever need another data type, you can use a `Dictionary<string, string>`.  I used `object` for the value in case you had other data types you'd be passing in.

Comment: i have other data types e.g. `DateTime` etc.  So i will stick with the `Dictionary <string, object>`